# How to store the values in Office js for add ins?

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js

I'm creating a word add-in using react js.

Currently, I'm using the browser local storage to store the values. Due to using local storage, the Word add-in is working as expected with Word Online but not with Word 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Office.js API, you can use the **Settings** object (`Office.context.document.settings`) to store data (as name/value pairs) in the host document. For details about how this works, see the documentation here:

- https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/settings

As the documentation indicates, the settings that you create/save using the Settings object are saved per add-in and per document.

Comment: It helped me lot, Thank you..! @Kim